# ORDER on Boolean field much slower than order on PK

Tags: mysql

I am doing a query, which orders the results on a BOOLEAN field (TINYINT(1)). It is indexed.

```
SELECT * FROM `main_catalog` ORDER BY `main_catalog`.`is_tv_on_itunes` ASC LIMIT 1
```

This takes 1.61 seconds to run. If I do the same query without an `ORDER BY`, it takes a fraction of the time:

```
SELECT * FROM `main_catalog` LIMIT 1
```

This takes 4.1ms to complete. Why does it take so much longer to sort on a boolean field than it does on a PK?

Comment: How many records does the table have? Even though you are using `LIMIT 1`, MySQL have to first sort the records before it returns  1 record. Also, you can check `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * FROM main_catalog ORDER BY main_catalog.is_tv_on_itunes ASC LIMIT 1`,  this will tell you if the index is being used or not.

Comment: another thing to check for is the value of sort_buffer_size. `show global variables like 'sort_buffer_size'` if this value is set too low it will impact the order by the default value is 2097144 if the value of sort_buffer_size is below the default try to set the value for the session and see if you see improvement `SET SESSION sort_buffer_size = 5242880`

Comment: @MIKE -- The value is: `sort_buffer_size 262144`. The table is about 1M rows and 312MB.

Comment: My assumption is the MySQL is not using the index because a whole table scan may be cheaper. I would think your records as about 50% 0 and %50 1. What is the value of sort_buffer_size? and can you show the output of `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * FROM main_catalog ORDER BY is_tv_on_itunes ASC LIMIT 1` and can you also show `show create table main_catalog`

Answer (score 0):

Why does it take so much longer to sort on a boolean field than it does on a PK?

That's easy.  The primary key has an index that makes it possible to retrieve the records in sorted order without doing a sort.  You have a simple query, so this index can be used for the retrieval.  (There is an additional optimization because the rows are in primary key order, but that is a small additional gain compared to having the index.)

You can create an index on `main_catalog(is_tv_on_itunes)` or something similar with additional fields.

And, just for the record, the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `main_catalog`
LIMIT 1
```

Does *not* sort on the primary key.  The results in a query are not guaranteed to be in any particular order.  If you want them in primary key order, then you need to add an `order by` statement to guarantee that.

Comment: Thanks, though in the above example the boolean field is indexed as well.

Comment: @user1436531 . . . Is it the first column in the index?